# Corrplot visualization

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, rstudio, r-corrplot

I try to use R package - corrplot.

An example, i do this code:

```
M<-cor(mtcars)
corrplot(M, method="circle")
```

[image]

I get this image. It's ok, but if I want to look it inr my RStudio, i get this:
[image]

The image is shifted down, part of the characters are not visible. If there were more variables to correlate, it would be much worse. Maybe there are customizable parameters for image output and / or centering it?

Comment: Am glad someone has finally asked this question